# xe.com web service response missing details that show in Postman

Tags: integration

I'm working on an integration to xe.com to pull current exchange rate into Salesforce.  When I make the call through Postman, I get back the expected exchange rate details like so:
[image: Postman screenshot]

But when I make the same call through Salesforce, I only receive back partial information, missing the list of rates.
[image: SFDC Results]

Anyone have ideas on where to go next?  Xe.com support is pushing back since it is a Salesforce call.  I can't figure out why the rates are not coming back when all other details are there.  I confirmed I send the same request via both methods and Postman works but SF leaves the 'to' rates list out.

Comment: How do you specify setEndpoint() ? did you put &to=CAD

Comment: I'm using string endpointurl='https: //xecdapi.xe.com /v1 /convert_from.json'; [spaces added to URL to avoid hyperlinking/auto format] r.setEndpoint(endpointurl); and r.setHeader('from', 'USD'); r.setHeader('to', 'CAD');

Comment: the is a difference between them. place whole url to endpoint: https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/convert_from/?from=USD&amount=1&to=CAD

Comment: Yes, with that tip I realized the to/from should not be headers but in the endpoint.  When I changed to System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https:// xecdapi.xe.com/v1/ convert_from.json/ ?from=USD&amount=1&to=CAD, Method=GET] it worked.  Thanks for that pointer.